# Font-size not displaying same size in Chrome and firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-size

I have a `<nav>` element and a `<div>` element and I want the second to the right of the first. In Chrome, it displays correct:

[image]

But in firefox:

[image]

I've found that the font-size in firefox is a bit larger than in Chrome. My css is this:

```
#mainnav .menu > ul > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

That is the font size for the items in the menu, if I change it to `12px` in firefox, it looks ok, like in chrome. I've found a property, `font-size-adjust` for firefox. Should I use this or there is a better way to make the font size look the same across browsers?

In case you want to test it in the site, here it is : [elbauldelprogramador.com](http://elbauldelprogramador.com/)

Comment: Always use CSS reset to make things more consistent.

Comment: By the way, it works absolutely fine on my machine.

Comment: In Firefox too?, In no one of my firefox works.

Comment: Looking at the shape of the C, you're not picking up the same font in your browsers.

Comment: It's look good in my machine please update your FF vrersion12.0

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz The font is `font-family: "Open Sans",Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;` in the CSS

Comment: @PawanLakhara I have firefox 29.0

Comment: @algui91 i think please check your browser zooming option press ctrl+0

Comment: No it's not: `#mainnav .menu > ul { font-family: "0",sans-serif; }`

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Ok, But that property is the same in Firefox and Chrome. Should I just use font-size-adjust?

Comment: It could be because of this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962979

Comment: in my machine , for rtl languages , i have this problem ... chrome and firefox can't show fonts with same weight ...